# How to use ExternalTaskSensor in Airflow using for loop?

Tags: python, airflow

I am trying to use multiple ExternalTaskSensor with different task_id using for loop.

I tried with the code below, and the result I expected is:

```
wait_for_task_0 -> poking 2023-07-09
wait_for_task_1 -> poking 2023-07-10
wait_for_task_2 -> poking 2023-07-11
...
wait_for_task_6 -> poking 2023-07-15
```

However, the actual result is shown below.

```
wait_for_task_0 -> poking 2023-07-15
wait_for_task_1 -> poking 2023-07-15
wait_for_task_2 -> poking 2023-07-15
...
wait_for_task_6 -> poking 2023-07-15
```

How should I modify my code to get the result I want?

This is my airflow dag ex:

```py
default_args = {
    'owner': 'jmkim',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime.datetime(2023, 7, 10, tzinfo=kst_tz),
    'retries': 3,
    'retry_delay': datetime.timedelta(minutes=5),
}

with DAG(
        dag_id="example_airflow_dag",
        default_args=default_args,
        schedule_interval="30 10 * * 1",
        catchup=False,
        tags=['weekly'],
        max_active_runs=1,
        concurrency=1
) as dag:

    # schedule_interval="30 8 * * *"
    with TaskGroup("wait_for_task_group", dag=dag) as wait_for_task_group:
        for day in range(0, 7):
            ExternalTaskSensor(
                task_id=f"wait_for_task_{day}",
                external_dag_id="target_dag_id",
                external_task_id="target_task_id",
                execution_date_fn=lambda x: x + datetime.timedelta(days=day) - datetime.timedelta(hours=2),
                mode="reschedule",
                timeout=3600,
                task_group=wait_for_task_group
            )

    ...

    wait_for_task_group >> my_task
```

Comment: Are you dynamically setting the `external_task_id`? If it's hardcoded like in the example (`"target_task_id"`), then it will only poke for that particular day. 

An alternative solution would be using [data aware scheduling](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/authoring-and-scheduling/datasets.html); this feature would allow downstream DAGs to begin when certain conditions are met (e.g. upstream tasks that have an `outlet` complete successfully)